# Why does account Power BI automatically sign out after few day?

Tags: powerbi, microsoft-graph-api, report

I have problem with Power BI,
My company are building report revenue by Power BI Pro and when I am building it with account Microsoft but a few days account automatically sign out.

I logged back in several times, but the next few days I had the same situation.
Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just a normal behaviour of power bi, you don't need to worry, you may be disconnected from time to time (specially if you don't use regularly).

If it happpens all the times you open power bi, hit the "stay connected" button after sign in.